# my website is not showing an image based button when it is opened in iphone safari. What seems to be the problem?

Tags: html, css

I coded this website as a side project. The front end works perfectly in every browser and device even safari laptop expect for iPhone safari.

Image of safari i phone display

[image]

The picture is there when you click the button it asks if you want to download but the whole thing is turned into the button

what seems to be the problem here?

```html
<section class="hero-wrap js-fullheight" style="background-color: black;">
<div class="container">
<div class="row description js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
    <div class="text">
    <h1 style="font-size:35px; font-family:monospace; text-align:center; padding-bottom:20px;">Have you watched mainstream anime (Naruto, Death Note etc) ?</h2></div>
                <form action="recc3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                     <button type="submit" name ="answer3" value=1>
                        <img src="{% static 'images/yes.png' %}" alt="yes" style="width:100%"></button></div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <button type="submit" name="answer3" value=0>
                        <img src="{% static 'images/no.png' %}" alt="no" style="width:100%"></button></div>
                 </div> 
              </form>
</div>
</div>      
</div>

  
</section>
```

Comment: Illegal HTML. You are not wrapping your divs correctly

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: close the `button` tag *before*  you close it's parent `div` tag (i.e. reverse the order of the two closing tags, x2)

Comment: I wrapped them in order now. The same problem is happening.